# Unable to connect worker node to kubernetes cluster

Tags: linux, kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04

Getting the below mentioned error while trying to connect to cluster from worker node.

Cluster version is `1.10.4` and node version is `1.11.0`

```
[discovery] Successfully established connection with API Server "10.148.0.2:6443"
[kubelet] Downloading configuration for the kubelet from the "kubelet-config-1.11" ConfigMap in the kube-system namespace
configmaps "kubelet-config-1.11" is forbidden: User "system:bootstrap:7fho7b" cannot get configmaps in the namespace "kube-system"
```

Comment: How did you connect your worker node to a cluster?

Comment: kubeadm join 10.148.0.2:6443 --token bs0g8l.xfr509n955yznfra --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:ffa01aae8b740ef1dff4ad36ae8d6f7b2f49e73022d4914d8108488eb6a59f88

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely check your version of kubeadm and kubelet, make sure the same version of these packages is used along all of your nodes.  Prior to installing, you should "mark and hold" your versions of these on your hosts:

#### check your current version of each:

kubelet --version

#### check kubeadm

kubeadm version

#### if they're different, you've got problems.   You should reinstall the same version among all your nodes and allow downgrades.  My versions in the command below are probably older than what is currently out, you can replace the version number with some more up to date, but this will work:

sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce=18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu kubelet=1.12.2-00 kubeadm=1.12.2-00 kubectl=1.12.2-00 --allow-downgrades

#### then, once they're installed, mark and hold them so they can't be upgraded automatically, and break your system

sudo apt-mark hold docker-ce kubelet kubeadm kubectl

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that you use various `kubeadm` versions, there is a mismatch between control (master) node and worker node for `kubelet-config-1.*` config maps.

Check your `Configmap` for `kube-system` namespace on your primary control node:

```
kubectl get configmap -n kube-system
```

I assume that result value for `kubelet-config` version will be different than `kubelet-config-1.11` from the error message.

Therefore, you should upgrade `kubeadm` to version 1.11 in order to match your worker node `kubeadm` version.

There was a similar case discussed on [GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/907).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not kubeadm version, but rather the kubelet version.

When you run `kubeadm join`, kubeadm will look on which kubelet version is installed in the host system, and then it will ask the API server for the correct configuration.

The code for this is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/03a145de8ad282764828f43821433001974718e9/cmd/kubeadm/app/phases/kubelet/config.go#L124):

```
// DownloadConfig downloads the kubelet configuration from a ConfigMap and writes it to disk.
// Used at "kubeadm join" time
func DownloadConfig(client clientset.Interface, kubeletVersion *version.Version, kubeletDir string) error {

    // Download the ConfigMap from the cluster based on what version the kubelet is
    configMapName := kubeadmconstants.GetKubeletConfigMapName(kubeletVersion)
```